# functionName is not a function, onClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change a parent component state by passing the setter function `setAccountNumberFilter` to the child and resetting it there. I got the error

> Account.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: accountNumberFunction is not a
> function

I tried all syntax variations of passing it to the child component through props (not redux). What am I missing?

app file (Parent)

```jsx
import Header from "./Header";
import Account from "./Account";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [accountNumberFilter, setAccountNumberFilter] = useState(0)
    return (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Account accountNumberFunction={() => setAccountNumberFilter(accountNumber)}/>
            <ActivityPanel accountNumberFilter={accountNumberFilter}/>
        </div>
    </React.StrictMode>
    );
};
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<App />);
export default App;
```

Account File (Child)

```jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Account = (accountNumberFunction) => {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/account/get_all")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setAccounts(data.accounts);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="accountContainer"
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
      }}
    >
      {accounts.map((accountObj, indx) => {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "300px",
              backgroundColor: "white",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              boxShadow:
                "inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.45)",
              borderRadius: "10px",
            }}
            key={accountObj.fields.accountNumber + indx}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>
                <button
                  onClick={() =>
                    accountNumberFunction(accountObj.fields.accountNumber)
                  }
                >
                  <a>{accountObj.fields.type}</a>
                </button>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

Comment: can you post what you tried? also you are currently not passing anything at all

Comment: I think you meant `const Account = ({ accountNumberFunction }) => { ... }`. The props parameter is an object. This can be closed as a **typo**

Comment: @phil Yes, you are right, I didnt deconstruct it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use accountNumberFunction the way you are using it you will need to modify the account component to destructure in place

```js
const Account = ({accountNumberFunction}) => {}
```

and when your passing it from parent change

```jsx
<Account accountNumberFunction={setAccountNumberFilter}/>
```